# sql server if exists issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I am stuck on the following stored procedure. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have two tables: TableA and TableB.

- TableA has Columns called silo, slow , and close.
- Table B has columns called silo, partno, slow, and close.

.

- I have an HMI program that is 
  sending me the silo and partno and I am sending back the slow and close.
- I first need to look at TableA and see if there is a silo and partno in tableA that matches what the HMI is sending me.
- If it does, i simply send back the slow and close to the HMI (output).
- If TableA doesn't have the silo and partno then I need to

  - look at TableB at only the silo and select the top 1( there could be multiple rows with the same silo number so i need the top 1) and send back the slow and close to the HMI.
  - I also need to insert the silo, partno (the hmi is sending me), the slow and close (from TableB) and into a new row in TableA.
- If this procedure is triggered multiple times, then it shouldn't keep inserting 
  rows in tableA.

I know the if exists or where not exists can be applied in this procedure; but i just don't know how to do this successfully. The code is below. I appreciate your time. Thank you very much

p.s. the errorout is to notify the hmi that if tableA and tableB doesn't have the existing silo, slow, and close, then to pop up a message box. thats all. 
     verification and notification purposes only.

```
USE [Product]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Proc  [Controls].[spSiloSettings]

    @Silo int
    ,@PartNo Varchar (50)
    ,@Slow float output 
    ,@Close  float output 
    ,@errorout int output
AS

if  exists (select slow, close from controls.TableA where  @silo = silo and @partno= partno)

set @errorout = 0

select @slow= slow, @close = close 
    from TableA
    where @silo = silo  

if not exists(select  top 1 @silo = silo,  @slow= slow, @close = close)
    From controls.TableB
    Where silo = @silo

insert into controls.TableA (silo, partno, slow, close) 
    values (@silo, @partno ,@slow, @close)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
USE [Product]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Proc  [Controls].[spSiloSettings]
    @Silo int
    ,@PartNo Varchar (50)
    ,@Slow float output 
    ,@Close  float output 
    ,@errorout int output
AS
BEGIN
    declare @found bit = 0

    set @errorout = 0

    select @slow = slow
    , @close = close 
    , @found = 1
    from controls.TableA 
    where silo = @silo 
    and partno = @partno 

    if @found != 1
    begin

        select top 1
          @found = 1
        , @slow= slow
        , @close = close
        From controls.TableB
        Where silo = @silo
        --order by something to ensure consistent results?

        if @found = 1
        begin
            insert into controls.TableA (silo, partno, slow, close) 
            values (@silo, @partno ,@slow, @close)
        end
        else
        begin
            @errorout = 1 --neither A nor B held the value we were after
        end
    end

END
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks NikoalMarkovinovic as well!